# Adobe CQ building process

Tags: adobe, aem

How many ways are to compile and run Adobe CQ5 ?

Using Apache Maven i know , but in our project they are not following maven architecture is there any other way to build and compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to integrate Java code into CQ5 is via OSGi bundles, which can be built with any suitable tool, there's nothing special about them. An OSGi bundle is just a java jar file with some additional headers in MANIFEST.MF, so in a pinch you could even build them with a text editor and the javac and jar tools.

CQ5 applications also uses scripts and content stored in the CRX content repository, if you had no external tools you could create that content using HTTP requests or CQ5's CRXDE explorer, and package that content using CQ5's Package Manager.

Various Maven plugins help make this easier, but they are not required to build CQ5 applications.

Answer (score 0):

CQ5 is delivered as compiled JAR files, so I understand your question to be, "What are ways to compile and run Adobe CQ5 applications?"

In addition to the [Eclipse/Maven combination](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/developmenttools/developing_with_eclipse.html), you can use the web-based [CRXDE Lite](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/developing/development_tools/developing_with_crxde_lite.html) tool, [IntelliJ](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/how_to/setting_up_an_intellij.html), and/or the CRXDE desktop tool.  My tech lead also likes to use NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom application Java code can be deployed as an OSGi bundle through the Felix console (a JAR file with a manifest file containing OSGi headers) and your component render scripts that may depend on said code (everything that would live under the /apps directory) is just a vault package (zip file containing specific metadata files; you can create a package and crack it open to see what files are needed), you can really put together a deployment package using a build tool like **Ant** as well.

Of course, I think if you can get Maven/Eclipse set up, it would be better to go that route.

- On Ant: http://ant.apache.org/
- On OSGi bundles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi#Bundles
- On packages in CQ: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/package_manager.html